# How to compile generator and coroutine using c++2a on Mac

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, generator, c++-coroutine

I am setting up my MacBook for C++20 and having problem to compile the code. I have installed latest Xcode, llvm and gcc. Here is the code that I am trying to compile

```
#include <chrono>
#include <experimental/coroutine>
#include <future>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

generator<int> getInts(int first, int last) {
  for (auto i = first; i <= last; ++i) {
    co_yield i;
  }
}

int main() {
  for (auto i : getInts(5, 10)) {
    std::cout << i << " ";
  }
}
```

however I am getting following error:

```
$ g++ gen.cpp -std=c++2a
In file included from gen.cpp:2:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/experimental/coroutine:66:5: warning: 
      <experimental/coroutine> cannot be used with this compiler [-W#warnings]
#   warning <experimental/coroutine> cannot be used with this compiler
    ^
```

appreciate any insight how to resolve this compile issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Coroutines TS has not been voted into C++20 (indeed, there have been three separate votes, with approval *not* achieving consensus in all of them), so even if GCC implemented it ([which it doesn't](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html)), it wouldn't be activated by the `-std=c++2a` switch.

Now, Clang does implement the Coroutines TS, which you have to turn on with `-fcoroutines-ts`. And apparently, you have to be using libc++.

Comment: @sbh: OK, please stop posting comments here. If you want to provide an alternate answer providing a detailed command line for doing what you want, use the "Add Answer" button. It is perfectly valid for you to add answers to your own questions. Adding comment after comment to an existing answer is not an appropriate way to get that information out there.

Comment: Whats the state now with XCode in 2022?  Is it finally implemented? Would really love to use it now.